# the better way of wring the same value in computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the code which is running properly, how can i write this piece of code better

```
if (!this.isThis) {
    return [                    
        { label: this.$t('profile'), value: this.acc.AccountNumber, id: 'ProfileNumber' },
    ]
} else {
    return [
        { label: this.$t('market'), value: this.acc.label, id: 'market' },
        { label: this.$t('profile'), value: this.acc.AccountNumber, id: 'ProfileNumber' },
        { label: this.$t('account'), value: this.acc.profile, id: 'account' }
    ]
}
```

can i use some better js code to handle this, above works but there are better ways to write

Comment: imo, that's as straightforward as it is. maybe remove `else` because it will exit on `return` anyway. that's what an `eslint` rule would do: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-else-return

Comment: I applaud your desire to optimize your code, make it slim and easier to maintain. Just remember that there is too much optimization. (Here's not the case though.)

Answer (score 0):

Given that they share the same middle element, you could rewrite it like this:

```js
return [
  ...this.isThis ? [{ label: this.$t('market'), value: this.acc.label, id: 'market' }] : [],
  { label: this.$t('profile'), value: this.acc.AccountNumber, id: 'ProfileNumber' },
  ...this.isThis ? [{ label: this.$t('account'), value: this.acc.profile, id: 'account' }] : [],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only this if else case you can remove else :

If your condition will work then it will return ifs value

By default (else) it can return your else value without else block .

Like this

```
if (!this.isThis) {
return [                    
    { label: this.$t('profile'), value: 
  this.acc.AccountNumber, id: 
  'ProfileNumber' }
]} 

return [
    { label: this.$t('market'), value: this.acc.label, id: 'market' },
    { label: this.$t('profile'), value: this.acc.AccountNumber, id: 'ProfileNumber' },
    { label: this.$t('account'), value: this.acc.profile, id: 'account' }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew Parks,

Perhaps, even smaller:

```js
return [
        { label: this.$t('profile'), 
          value: this.acc.AccountNumber, 
          id: 'ProfileNumber' },
        ...this.isThis ? [{ label: this.$t('market'), 
                            value: this.acc.label, 
                            id: 'market' },
                          { label: this.$t('account'), 
                            value: this.acc.profile, 
                            id: 'account' }
                         ] : [],
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional truthy array elements can be conventionally added with short circuit and then filtered:

```
return [
    this.isThis && { label: this.$t('market'), value: this.acc.label, id: 'market' },
    { label: this.$t('profile'), value: this.acc.AccountNumber, id: 'ProfileNumber' },
    this.isThis && { label: this.$t('account'), value: this.acc.profile, id: 'account' }
].filter(Boolean)
```

It still may be more verbose but easier to read with conditional `push`.